# WAMP - PHP shell_exec() problem

Tags: php, svn, command-line, permissions, wamp

I'm using WAMP as a server, and I have a need to execute svn, which can be found in my Windows directory: C:/Program Files/Subversion/bin/

The problem, is that when I launch the php program from the server, it won't produce output. It works from the command line, which makes me think this is a permissions problem with WAMP. However after giving it unlimited power, it still won't execute svn commands unless I call it from the command line.

I've tried calling it with the full path to svn, and it's regular path. Other commands like "dir" work fine.

To clarify my question: How can I execute svn from php through WAMP?

Comment: Also, are you calling `svn` with its full path?

Comment: Both full path and just with svn, both have the same result.

Comment: Please paste the actual line where you try to execute 'svn'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use free svn classes instead, they don't require svn module:
http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3427.ht
http://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a [whole bunch](http://php.net/svn) of functions which deal explicitly with svn repositories and doesn't require you to use any system()-type functions.

Since you said you cannot use the various svn functions, try the following:

```
<?php
    $cmd = 'set PATH';
    echo '<pre>' , shell_exec( $cmd ) , '</pre>';
?>
```

See what that returns (look for the PATH environment variable). See what PATH contains.

You may have to add the Subversion folder to your PATH:

```
<?php
    $cmd = 'set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\"; svn up';
    shell_exec( $cmd );
?>
```

Hopefully, setting the PATH will solve your problem.

Comment: Those require you to install an svn module, which isn't possible in my environment.

Comment: 'set PATH' returns my path with the Subversion folder at the end. I tried for the heck of it adding the Subversion folder to the path again, but it didn't work. Thanks for trying to help though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem too and can solve this problem, make sure you use username and password (if need)

eg. svn update *"\my\project\"* --username *[myusername]* --password *[mypassword]*

If not, no output and svn still wait for you enter that.

P.S. When I log on and run svn on cmd, it not request username and password but when I run on PHP you need it. Hopefully, it will solve your problem.